# Integration of other js/app components (e.g. jQuery) into react.js SPAs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, integration, single-page-application

It seems pretty challenging to integrate other js libraries and apps into single side applications based on react.js - except for using iframes.
Does anyone know a proper solution/workaround for visual integration of non-react apps into react.js SPAs?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to integrate?

Comment: this is not a clear question

Comment: @FredVollmer We wanna integrate a bunch of different apps and js libraries into an single side application based on react.js.

Comment: @webdeb If you tell me what's unclear I would love to provide more details.

Comment: Its unclear which libraries you want to integrate into a React App. If you you just Write *its difficult* you should explain what you have tried and what failed. Otherwise there is no way to help you and the whole question doesnt make sense.

Comment: @webdeb I see ;) One library would be jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You will have problems to integrate any kind of libraries, which are working with the DOM directly.

jQuery (or many of jQuery-Plugins) are manipulating the DOM. People which decide to use React, don't want to access the the DOM directly, instead the DOM is generated by React automatically.

So, there are many JS libraries which you can use with React, like Redux, underscore.js, lodash.js, moment.js, i18next.js and so on.. But this libraries are basically for Data-management, Modeling, Validations, API communication and so on.

All UI / DOM Rendering stuff should be managed by React Components.